# What is the usage of as(Function<? super Mono<T>,P> transformer)

Tags: java, project-reactor

can someone please explain `as(Function<? super Mono<T>,P> transformer)` and its practical usage. I am not getting it on its official document clearly about its practical use case. Thanks

Comment: Just a transformation function of an output `Mono<T>` to something custom, representing as `P`.

Comment: @Nikolas Any simple example

Comment: See my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It is just a transformation function of a `Mono<T>` to something custom, representing as `P`.

A simple case is explained right at the [`Mono::as`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#as-java.util.function.Function-) documentation which shows how a `Mono` might be subscribed again using `Flux`:

```
mono.as(Flux::from).subscribe()
```

At the very same method description a bit below, there is a link for another method [`Mono:: compose`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#compose-java.util.function.Function-).

> **See Also:**
>
> [for a bounded conversion to {@link Publisher}](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#compose-java.util.function.Function-)

This method is based on the `Mono::as`, however, is created for a more specified case:

```
mono.compose(original -> original.log());
```